# jQuery $.ajax jsonp parsererror

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I looked through all the .ajax jsonp parsererror in stackoverflow and still couldn't figure how to get rid of this error.

```
JSONP Error: parsererror Error: jQuery21108956659331452101_1444622439301 was not called
JSONP was retrieved successfully
```

It was retrieved successfully and still not clear why I am getting the parsererror. Codes below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$.ajax(this.dataSrc, {
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('JSONP Error: ' + status + error);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        console.log('JSONP was retrieved successfully');
    }
});
```

Comment: check whether the said url is returning a jsonp response... looks like it is not... check what is the response content

Comment: the response should have `callback` response, check this at your response function @Jason Tang

Comment: Thanks! I am able to see the response and the data is rendering fine on the page. It just that I wanted to get rid of the "parsererror". Is it because the json data is stored in the JS file that's why I am getting the parser error?